# Get data from Laravel(in api folder) to Vue (placed in another folder)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have Laravel in api folder and Vue is in the root folder, and I  try to pass data from Laravel to Vue Components.From what I find I must use axios for this but I didn't know how. I am looking for a solution for some hours now, but nothing worked. PS. I didn't do anything in blade till now. Any help, please !?

[image]

**api/routes/api.php**

```
Route::get('/content', 'ContentController@index');
```

**ContentController**

```
    public function index() {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return $customers;    
}
```

**Vue component**

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: "Home"
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created your Vue app using the Vue CLI, running vue serve starts your application at a local URL, you need to have your Laravel API app running as well so you can request data from it using Axios in Vue components

```
cd api
php artisan serve
```

Then in your template, you should have something like this

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            databaseConfiguration: "",
            errors: {}
        };
    },
    name: "Home",
    created: function() {
        axios
            .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/content")
            .then(response => {
                this.databaseConfiguration = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.errors.push(error);
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
};
</script>
```

Here's a [full working example app on GitHub](https://github.com/CaddyDz/vue-cli-laravel-api)
Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I did this:  export default {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8081/content').then(response => console.log(response.data)),
  name: "Home"
};    but it's not good

Comment: Sorry, I get an error for a ' , ' , I guess that was something wrong where I place it so I edit the code.    export default {
  name: "Home",
   created: function() {
    axios.get("/content").then(response => console.log(response.data));
  }
};     -> the error is for Unexpected console statement, on line "console.log(response.data);

Comment: Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js): , I Copy/Past your code. I think that is from eslint-loader, I will do some research ,and I will get back to you with an answer, thank you!

Comment: You can ignore that, eslint is just a linter to make sure your code is formatted properly

Comment: It Fails to compile /2 errors found, for console.log. I will look for a solution with this and I will get back.

Comment: I pushed an example app with your code on GitHub here https://github.com/CaddyDz/vue-cli-laravel-api

Comment: I tested your code, and I replaced in mine and it works, thank's alot for your time! I'll give you +1, but after I get 15 reputation(now I can't).